# Ui Grid Angular JS : Export all Visible Data when using Built in Pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, export, angular-ui-grid

I'm working on a website using angularJS and UI Grid. 
I display some datas i receive from my backend , with ui grid.
Since i have a lot of data, i use the ui grid paganation.
I can filter and hide columns.

When i try to "export all visible data" , only the current page is exported.

It may be normal since other pages aren't visible, but i would like to find a solution to export all my filtered data, and not only the current page .

I can't find something like this in Ui Grid Docs

Thanks

Comment: Did my answer below help?  Did you need anything else?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I didn't try it yet. I'm a student with a part time job, I'm not in enterprise everyday :( . I'll tell you if it worked !

Comment: I certainly understand, matey.  Great to have you on the Stack Overflow online community.  You're going about it the right way if you want to make it in enterprise everyday :).  Let me know how it goes when you have a chance.  Happy to help!

Comment: I tried to use you code , with some adjustments to make it work in my code (   gridoption replacement + "i don't use $scope " ) and it's all good. Thanks a lot :) . Now i'll try to get the pdf export aswell , and try to put the button in the ui grid menu panel , instead of nativ "export visible data " buttons

Comment: I updated my answer to include PDF export and Custom Menu Options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, this is how you'd export not only your current page, but all your filtered data.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.exporter']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridExporterService', 'uiGridExporterConstants',
  function($scope, uiGridExporterService, uiGridExporterConstants) {
    $scope.export = function() {
      var exportData = [];
      var exportColumnHeaders = $scope.gridOptions.showHeader ? uiGridExporterService.getColumnHeaders($scope.gridApi.grid, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE) : [];
      angular.forEach($scope.gridApi.grid.rows, function(row) {
        if (row.visible) {
          var values = [];
          angular.forEach(exportColumnHeaders, function(column) {
            var value = row.entity[column.name];
            values.push({
              value: value
            });
          });
          exportData.push(values);
        }
      });
      var csvContent = uiGridExporterService.formatAsCsv(exportColumnHeaders, exportData, ',');
      uiGridExporterService.downloadFile($scope.gridOptions.exporterCsvFilename, csvContent, $scope.gridOptions.exporterOlderExcelCompatibility);
    };
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableFiltering: true,
      paginationPageSizes: [5, 10, 15],
      paginationPageSize: 5,
      exporterCsvFilename: 'filteredData.csv',
      onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      },
      columnDefs: [{name: 'FirstName'}, {name: 'LastName'}, {name: 'Job'}],
      data: [{"FirstName": "Sonny", "LastName": "Jayet", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Tim", "LastName": "Harker", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Sonny", "LastName": "Jayet", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Tim", "LastName": "Harker", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Sonny", "LastName": "Jayet", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Tim", "LastName": "Harker", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Sonny", "LastName": "Jayet", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Tim", "LastName": "Harker", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Sonny", "LastName": "Jayet", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Tim", "LastName": "Harker", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Sonny", "LastName": "Jayet", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Tim", "LastName": "Harker", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Sonny", "LastName": "Jayet", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Tim", "LastName": "Harker", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Sonny", "LastName": "Jayet", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Tim", "LastName": "Harker", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Sonny", "LastName": "Jayet", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Tim", "LastName": "Harker", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Sonny", "LastName": "Jayet", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Tim", "LastName": "Harker", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"},
             {"FirstName": "Sonny", "LastName": "Jayet", "Job": "Stack Overflow User"}]
    };
  }
]);
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div[ui-grid] {
  height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.min.css" />
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="export()">Export Filtered &amp; Paged Grid</button>
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-exporter class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** PDF export, and custom grid menu options.

Code to decide on PDF or CSV export:

```
var content;
if (format=="csv") {
  content = uiGridExporterService.formatAsCsv(exportColumnHeaders, exportData, ',');
  uiGridExporterService.downloadFile($scope.gridOptions.exporterCsvFilename, content, $scope.gridOptions.exporterOlderExcelCompatibility);
} else {
  content = uiGridExporterService.prepareAsPdf($scope.gridApi.grid, exportColumnHeaders, exportData);
  pdfMake.createPdf(content).open();
}
```

Grid option code to hide existing menu options and add custom menu options.

```
enableGridMenu: true,
exporterMenuCsv: false,
exporterMenuPdf: false,
gridMenuCustomItems: [{
  title: 'CSV Export (Filtered & Paged Grid)',
  action: function() {
    $scope.export('csv');
  },
  order: 210
}, {
  title: 'PDF Export (Filtered & Paged Grid)',
  action: function() {
    $scope.export('pdf');
  },
  order: 250
}],
```

Here's a working Plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/xBvc4094CIu6oGDZXZx7?p=preview.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did have to add a 'showHeader: true' to my grid options to get this work work.  That was the only real issue, after that I had to re-work some of my unique issues with exporting, for example date formats and also some programatically added columns.  But other than that, your code was terrific.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work. Did not like the other approach where you use the uiGridExporterService because that seems to be exporting only the raw data.

```
onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
    gridApi.core.on.rowsVisibleChanged($scope, function () {
        // match export enabled per row to visible property. This is in order to force export only of filtered data.
        gridApi.grid.rows.forEach(function (row) {
            row.exporterEnableExporting = row.visible;
        });
    });
}
```